# trouble with d3.js updating bar chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, nested

I'm trying to make a bar chart that updates on  loop with data I have in a json file but I can't access the data JSON data because there is an array nested inside of an array

```
//X Scale
var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(['Black', 'Hispanic', 'Other', 'White'])
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(0.2);

//Y Scale
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 120000])
    .range([height, 0]);

//X Axis
var xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(x);
g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxisCall);

//Y axis
var yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft(y)
    .tickFormat(function(d){return '$' + d; })
g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxisCall);

//Bars
var rects = g.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data[0])
    var groupOne = data[0];


//Problem is below
    console.log(groupOne.standings[0]);
    rects.enter()
        .append('rect')
            .**attr('y', function(d){return y(data[0].standings); })
            .attr('x', function(d){return x(d.standings) })
            .attr('width', function(d){return height - y(data[0].standings);})**
            .attr('width', x.bandwidth)
            .attr('fill', 'grey');


//Here is a sample of the json data
[
  {
    "standings": [
      {
      "Black": 36815,
      "Hispanic": 39742,
      "Other": 58884,
      "White": 86229
    }
    ],
    "year": "1989"
  },
```

my bar chart should show the values listed for standings across the bars, eventually letting me update the chart through each year.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet doesn't close all the parentheses, but it seems data[0] is an array item that is an object with two attributes, standings and year.  So to reference the number 36815 in your example, your ref is data[0].standings[0].Black   . Meanwhile your ref for the year 1989 is data[0].year